# Facing UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning warning message in web3 infura

Tags: web3js, infura

So far, I'm trying to get transactions list using web3 & infura by websocket provider.

Here is my code

```
const Web3 = require("web3");

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/YOUR_PROJECT_ID'));

let subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs',{'address':'ANY_ADDRESS','fromBlock':7244886})
subscription.subscribe((error, result) => {
    if (error) throw error;
})
.on('data',async (txns) => {
    console.log(txns)
});
```

However, I'm getting response successfully. But before receiving transactions, there is a warning arrives like below

```
(node:5382) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: callback is not a function
    at /var/www/html/test/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-core-subscriptions/dist/web3-core-subscriptions.cjs.js:119:11
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:5382) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5382) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

web3 version (npm list web3) - **web3@1.0.0-beta.46**

web3-core-subscriptions version (npm list web3-core-subscriptions) -

```
+-- web3-core-subscriptions@1.0.0-beta.46 
+-- web3-eth@1.0.0-beta.36
| +-- web3-core-method@1.0.0-beta.36
| | `-- web3-core-subscriptions@1.0.0-beta.36  extraneous
| +-- web3-core-subscriptions@1.0.0-beta.36  extraneous
| `-- web3-eth-contract@1.0.0-beta.36
|   `-- web3-core-subscriptions@1.0.0-beta.36  extraneous
`-- web3-shh@1.0.0-beta.36
  `-- web3-core-subscriptions@1.0.0-beta.36  extraneous
```

Comment: You probably want to pass a callback to `web3.eth.subscribe` as the third input argument (see https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html#example).

Answer (score 0):

You should update web3 to a later beta version: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2364. This was fixed post 46.

Comment: I tried with `npm install web3@latest` but it still installs `web3@1.0.0-beta.46` version.